# how to build a transparent private gem source server

Tags: ruby, rubygems

My connection to default gem source server http://rubygems.org/ is slow. So I am looking for a method to build a private gem server on a machine which I have fast connection to. I have some questions after reading gems doc:

1. If I have multiple gem sources , what is the order which source is used when running `gem install xxx`?
2. Will any method documented in http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18 help build a transparent gem server? "Transparent" means I need this only one gem server in my gem sources, and when I request a gem from this server, it will first serve the gem from cache. If the gem is not in cache yet, the server will try to download it from http://rubygems.org/, serve and cache it.
3. If the answer for question 2 is "No", how can I build a transparent gem source server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just installing the pre-release bundler, which is several orders of magnitude faster due to major architectural changes.  It's not just your connection to rubygems that is slow; it's that painful for all of us ;) `gem install bundler --pre` will give you a much faster bundler.

That said, if you really want a loca gem server, try Gem in a box:

https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox

Comment: If I understand it correctly, geminabox only manages those gems that we manually uploaded to it. Seems not very convinient.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few projects that are specifically made to run a RubyGems.org mirror:

- https://github.com/YorickPeterse/gem-mirror
- https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror